# Segurar a imagem e mandar pra link no Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, android-eclipse

Segurar a imagem e mandar pra link no Android Studio
Utilizo um ImageView que quando clica executa uma função, mas gostaria que quando a imagem fosse pressionada, foi feita outra ação, que seria diferente de somente um toque simples na imagem. Ou seja, o ImageView com 2 funções, 1 de toque simples e a outra de pressionar a imagem. Como cria essa função de pressionar a imagem?

Obrigado

Comment: Poderia adicionar o seu layout?

Comment: @LennoardSilva fiz uma pergunta detalhando
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/329922/clique-normal-e-longo-s%C3%B3-funcionam-ap%C3%B3s-dar-um-primeiro-clique-no-imageview

Answer (score 1):

Para o toque simples, utilize o método [setOnClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener) e para pressionar utilize [setOnLongClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener).

Segue um exemplo:

```
  imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LongClick! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Eu fiz isso, mas não funciona no primeiro clique, precisa dar um clique e após ele ai sim, funciona as duas funções, click e long.