# Clique normal e longo só funcionam após dar um primeiro clique no ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, android-activity

Estou com um problema que quando clico na imagem, na primeira vez não acontece nada, só após o primeiro clique que funciona a função de clique simples e clique longo.

Código XML:

```
<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/idimagem" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:onClick="clickimagem" 
android:src="@drawable/imagem" />
```

Código JAVA:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
ImageView idimagem; 
[.....] 
public void clickimagem(View v) { 
idimagem= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.idimagem); 
idimagem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
@Override public void onClick(View v) { 
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
idimagem.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() { 
@Override public boolean onLongClick(View v) { 
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LongClick! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
return true; 
} 
}); 
}
```

Preciso fazer funcionar logo de primeira, e não após ter que dar um clique.

Answer (score 0):

Vindo [dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/329589/segurar-a-imagem-e-mandar-pra-link-no-android-studio), me parece claro o que está acontecendo.
Deixe-me tentar reproduzir o fluxo da sua aplicação:

Você tem definido um `android:onClick="clickimagem"` na sua ImageView, que quando é clicada chama o **`clickimagem(View v)`**

```
public void clickimagem(View v) { 
    idimagem= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.idimagem); 
    idimagem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override public void onClick(View v) { 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        } 
    }); 
    idimagem.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() { 
        @Override public boolean onLongClick(View v) { 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LongClick! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            return true; 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

E foi consumido e evento de clique normalmente, mas nele não há nenhuma ação a não ser `setOnClickListener(...)` e `setOnLongClickListener(...)` portanto, a partir de agora, sua ImageView tem um outro OnClickListener. É por isso que você precisa de 2 cliques para mostrar o Toast.

#### 1 - Remova o android:onClick

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/idimagem" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/imagem" />
```

#### 2 - No método onCreate, defina os click listeners

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // [...]
    idimagem = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.idimagem);
    idimagem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }
    });

    idimagem.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LongClick! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

#### 3 - Remova o public void clickimagem(View v) da sua activity

Comment: Não funcionou, o aplicativo crash ao iniciar. Provavelmente por eu ter adicionado isso no onCreate